# Custom actions not showing up on iOS push notifications

Tags: ios, cordova, apple-push-notifications, phonegap-pushplugin

I'm using [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) to receive push notifications with custom actions on an iOS application. Everything seems to be set up properly, but I still don't get the action buttons.

Here's my `PushNotification.init`:

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    var push = PushNotification.init({
        "ios": {
            "alert": "true",
            "vibration": true,
            "badge": "true",
            "sound": "true",
            "categories": {
                "approveOnly": {
                    "yes": {
                        "title": "Approve",
                        "foreground": true,
                        "destructive": false
                    },
                },
                "approveOrReprove": {
                    "yes": {
                        "title": "Approve",
                        "foreground": true,
                        "destructive": false
                    },
                    "no": {
                        "title": "Reprove",
                        "foreground": true,
                        "destructive": true
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    });
},
```

This seems to generate the appropriate Obj-C structure, by my logs:

```
2015-12-28 18:12:51.314 Approval Inbox[989:131023] PushPlugin.register: better button setup
2015-12-28 18:12:51.314 Approval Inbox[989:131023] categories: key approveOrReprove
2015-12-28 18:12:51.315 Approval Inbox[989:131023] yes button added
2015-12-28 18:12:51.315 Approval Inbox[989:131023] no button added
2015-12-28 18:12:51.315 Approval Inbox[989:131023] Adding category approveOrReprove
2015-12-28 18:12:51.315 Approval Inbox[989:131023] categories: key approveOnly
2015-12-28 18:12:51.315 Approval Inbox[989:131023] yes button added
2015-12-28 18:12:51.315 Approval Inbox[989:131023] Adding category approveOnly
```

It seems I`m also sending push notifications properly. This is the log of the object that's being sent:

```
{
    "aps": {
        "sound": "beep.wav",
        "alert":{
            "title": " long string",
            "body": "long string"
        },
        "content-available": 1,
        "category": "approveOrReprove"
    }
}
```

I receive the notification properly, and as I receive them, I log the notification event. Here's all I've got (`category is there`):

```
2015-12-28 18:16:02.686 Approval Inbox[989:130923] Notification received
2015-12-28 18:16:02.686 Approval Inbox[989:130923] Push Plugin key: alert
2015-12-28 18:16:02.687 Approval Inbox[989:130923] Push Plugin key: category
2015-12-28 18:16:02.687 Approval Inbox[989:130923] Push Plugin key: sound
2015-12-28 18:16:02.687 Approval Inbox[989:130923] Push Plugin key: content-available
2015-12-28 18:16:02.702 Approval Inbox[989:130923] event: notification
2015-12-28 18:16:02.702 Approval Inbox[989:130923] {"title":"long string","sound":"beep.wav","additionalData":{"foreground":false,"category":"approveOrReprove","content-available":1},"message":"long string"}
```

I fell like `"foreground":false` and `category` showing up inside `additionalData` aren't good signs, but I can't see how this could be causing the issue.

Does anybody see where I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: I tried to add the appropriate phonegap-plugin-push tag, but it's not created yet, and I don't have enough points to create it. So I added the old one hoping someone watching for it would be able to fix it. Sorry if it wasn't the appropriate way of doing this.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score -1):

Use this plugin:

cordova plugin add com.pushbots.push

Comment: AFAIK that plugin depends on PushBots, which is a third part service service, which I may not want to use.